# How does OnSave work in Castle ActiveRecord?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I am new to Castle ActiveRecord and am having a little difficulty with updating an object before it is saved.  After reading the doco I expected OnSave or BeforeSave to always update the object prior to the database call, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Sometimes the value is set, sometimes it is not.  I have tried both OnSave and BeforeSave and from what I can tell looking in NH Prof sometimes the value is just NULL.  I have tried Flushing, SaveAndFlush, SaveCopy, etc with no change.

Here's my sample code:

```
[ActiveRecord]
public class Blog : ActiveRecordValidationBase<Blog>
{
    [PrimaryKey] public int Id { get; set; }
    [Property] public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [Property] public string Name { get; set; }       
    [Property] public string Author { get; set; }

    protected override void OnSave()
    {
        Author = "Test Author 1";

        base.OnSave();
    }
}

// in a test:
var blog = new Blog { Name = "First Blog", CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow };
blog.Save();


INSERT INTO Blog (
    CreatedOn, 
    Name, 
    Author
)
VALUES (
    '2011-07-25T14:48:06.00' /* @p0 */, 
    'First Blog' /* @p1 */,
    NULL /* @p2 */
)
```

Is this a flushing issue, am I not understanding how OnSave works, or is it something else?  I am using the beta 3.0 version of ActiveRecord from Nuget, is that the issue?  Any help would be great, thanks.

**Update**

After looking at this more I think I see the issue.  When the field is not nullable it fails on the insert.  But if the field is nullable separate Insert and Update commands are generated back to back and it works.

Can I have a non-nullable field in a database be set in OnSave with ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the

```
    Save()
```

method and implement your logic there in a similar way you are doing with OnSave, it should work as you want.